# How to insert Header in Word file by C# programming in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, office-interop

I am selecting word file from openfiledialog control,
now my question is: how can I set the header of word file by selecting path 
I tried `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section` also but this is for new create file .

My code:

```
public void addheader()
{
    string temp_path = textbox1.text
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in temp_path.Sections)
    {
        //Get the header range and add the header details.
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range headerRange = section.Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
        headerRange.Fields.Add(headerRange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage);
        headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
        headerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlue;
        headerRange.Font.Size = 10;
        headerRange.Text = "Header text goes here";
    }
}
```

Is there any way to set the header by path of word file?

Comment: Open word, start the Macro Recorder, manually do your stuff, stop recording, press alt+F11 to view the code and you can see the methods that you need to use.

Comment: @Alex thanks but i need to do by programming .

Comment: Yes, but if you look at the recorded VBA code you will be able to see what object methods are used to add & edit a header, you then replicate that code in C#.

Comment: means, you want to open a word doc and then update it's header and close it, rigjht?

Answer (score 4):

Sample Try,

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateDocument();
        }

      //Create document method
        private void CreateDocument()
        {
            try
            {
                //Create an instance for word app
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

                //Set animation status for word application
                winword.ShowAnimation = false;

                //Set status for word application is to be visible or not.
                winword.Visible = false;

                //Create a missing variable for missing value
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                //Create a new document
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = winword.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                //Add header into the document
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in document.Sections)
                {
                    //Get the header range and add the header details.
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range headerRange = section.Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
                    headerRange.Fields.Add(headerRange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage);
                    headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
                    headerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlue;
                    headerRange.Font.Size = 10;
                    headerRange.Text = "Header text goes here";
                }

                //Add the footers into the document
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section wordSection in document.Sections)
                {
                    //Get the footer range and add the footer details.
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range footerRange = wordSection.Footers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
                    footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdDarkRed;
                    footerRange.Font.Size =10;
                    footerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
                    footerRange.Text = "Footer text goes here";
                }

                //adding text to document
                document.Content.SetRange(0, 0);
                document.Content.Text = "This is test document "+ Environment.NewLine;

                //Add paragraph with Heading 1 style
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para1 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);                
                object styleHeading1 = "Heading 1";
                para1.Range.set_Style(ref styleHeading1);                
                para1.Range.Text = "Para 1 text";
                para1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

                //Add paragraph with Heading 2 style
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para2 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
                object styleHeading2 = "Heading 2";
                para2.Range.set_Style(ref styleHeading2);
                para2.Range.Text = "Para 2 text";
                para2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

                //Create a 5X5 table and insert some dummy record
                Table firstTable = document.Tables.Add(para1.Range, 5, 5, ref missing, ref missing);

                firstTable.Borders.Enable = 1;
                foreach (Row row in firstTable.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (Cell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        //Header row
                        if (cell.RowIndex == 1)
                        {
                            cell.Range.Text = "Column " + cell.ColumnIndex.ToString();
                            cell.Range.Font.Bold = 1;
                            //other format properties goes here
                            cell.Range.Font.Name = "verdana";
                            cell.Range.Font.Size = 10;
                            //cell.Range.Font.ColorIndex = WdColorIndex.wdGray25;                            
                            cell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = WdColor.wdColorGray25;
                            //Center alignment for the Header cells
                            cell.VerticalAlignment = WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalCenter;
                            cell.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;

                        }
                        //Data row
                        else
                        {
                            cell.Range.Text = (cell.RowIndex - 2 + cell.ColumnIndex).ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Save the document
                object filename = @"c:\temp1.docx";
                document.SaveAs2(ref filename);
                document.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                document = null;
                winword.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                winword = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Document created successfully !");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Will Be,
[image]